# GAS for fetch data from webpage to spreadsheet and check it against last one saved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I have a script that:

- fetches data from a webpage
- pastes it to a spreadsheet
- is executed every day with time-driven trigger

I have two problems so far:

1. Data on desired webpage isn't refreshed every day and my question is
   is it possible to make some adjustments that the script doesn't save
   data from webpage to SS if that data on webpage is same as last one
   saved? Maybe to test last one row from webpage to last one from
   spreadsheet? How to do that?
2. Second problem is that script is executed and the all data is saved 
   to SS but I get this message:

> "Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 8. (line 115, file "Code")"

Line 115 of the code is:

```
  eigenSheet.getRange(eigenRow, 1, eigenValues.length, eigenValues[0].length).setValues(eigenValues);
```

I think that the problem maybe is that on webpage I have empty rows sometimes? Is that a problem or sth else and how to fix it?

The whole script code is here:

```
regularSheetName = "Regular method";
eigenSheetName = "EIGENVECTOR Analysis";

function updateSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var regularSheet = ss.getSheetByName(regularSheetName);
  var eigenSheet = ss.getSheetByName(eigenSheetName);

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'CET', "dd.MM.yyyy");

  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch("link").getContentText().split('======================================================================================================');

  if(content.length<2){
    return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Unable to fetch data.");
  }

  var strLines = content[1].split("\n");

  var regularValues = [];
  var eigenValues = [];

  var isRegular = true;
  var ignore = false;
  for(var i=1;i<strLines.length;i++){
    var str = strLines[i];

    if(str.length<10){
      if(isRegular){
        ignore = true;
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }else if(str.indexOf("EFAVORITE")>-1){
      ignore = false;
      isRegular = false;

      i++;
      str = strLines[i];
    }else if(str.indexOf("endfile")>-1){
      ignore = true;
    }

    if(!ignore){
      if(isRegular){
        //process regular method rows
        var lineSplit = str.split(" ");
        var row = [date];

        var curVal = "";
        for(var j=0;j<lineSplit.length;j++){
          if(lineSplit[j]===""){
            continue;
          }

          if((row.length==1&&curVal==="")||(isWord(lineSplit[j])&&isWord(lineSplit[j-1]))){
            if(curVal!=""){
              curVal += " ";
            }
            curVal += lineSplit[j];
          }else{
            row.push(curVal);
            curVal = lineSplit[j].replace(".", ",");
          }
        }
        row.push(curVal);

        regularValues.push(row);
      }else{
        //process eigen rows
        var lineSplit = str.split(" ");
        var row = [];

        var curVal = "";
        for(var j=0;j<lineSplit.length;j++){
          if(lineSplit[j]===""){
            continue;
          }

          if((row.length==0&&curVal==="")||(isWord(lineSplit[j])&&isWord(lineSplit[j-1]))){
            if(curVal!=""){
              curVal += " ";
            }
            curVal += lineSplit[j];
          }else{
            if(row.length==1&&curVal!="@"&&curVal!="N@"&&curVal!="N"){
              row.push("");
            }

            if(row.length>0){
              row.push(curVal);
            }else{
              row.push(date);
            }
            curVal = lineSplit[j].replace(".", ",");
          }
        }

        if(row.length==6&&curVal!="@"){
          row.push("");
        }

        row.push(curVal);

        eigenValues.push(row);
      }
    }
  }

  //append to sheets
  var regRow = regularSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  regularSheet.getRange(regRow, 1, regularValues.length, regularValues[0].length).setValues(regularValues);

  var eigenRow = eigenSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  eigenSheet.getRange(eigenRow, 1, eigenValues.length, eigenValues[0].length).setValues(eigenValues);
}

function isWord(checkStr){
  return (checkStr.indexOf("%")==-1 && checkStr!="@" && checkStr!="N@" && checkStr!="N" && isNaN(checkStr));
}
```

Comment: Apparently your data is not rectangular it looks like the first row has less columns in it than some of the remaining rows

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Range.getValues().filter(function(r){return r.join('').length;});//if r.join.length is zero the row is empty
```

Comment: Cooper, could you please expand the answer to include some explanation about why it is a good solution (for others - and it is)?

Answer (score 1):

**Supplementary answer**

Long ago I created a utility to lessen the debugging time in tricky situations when one has to apply a set of values received from one source `Range` to another:

```
/**
 * @summary checks if range can accept an array of values
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Range} rng 
 * @param {any[][]} values
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
const checkBounds = (rng, values) => {
    const targetRows = rng.getHeight();
    const targetCols = rng.getWidth();

    const { length } = values;
    const [firstRow] = values;

    return length === targetRows &&
        firstRow.length === targetCols;
};
```

**Empty rows**

In addition to Cooper's answer, you can also check if the row is empty with this, taking advantage of the fact that [`Boolean()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/Boolean) constructor returns false on falsy values (you have to be careful, as a row filled with `0`s will also be filtered out):

```
const isEmpty = (row) => row.every(Boolean);
```

> Or just use the built-in method service [`isBlank()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank) method